# Google search error: “Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network”

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

From the last 10 days or so I'm getting this error when google searching.

Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot. Why did this happen?

I have to go and click some catpcha in order to proof I'm not a robot.

I tried all the tricks I found here https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/4769760?hl=en

Then I ran the antivirus (I'm on MacOS), and it was clean.

It is true that I have some 10 or 20 tabs open because I research a lot, but it is normal for any IT person, I don't see the unsual stuff their system is detecting.

I watched my open ports and connections with netstat -ap tcp , and still I don't see anything unusual that ring the bell to me.

But the last 2 days my company was under heavy cyberattack and I now wonder whether some malware was somehow introduced and this is the reason there is some unusual traffic.

Google says this:

```
What Google considers automated traffic

Sending searches from a robot, computer program, automated service, or search scraper
Using software that sends searches to Google to see how a website or webpage ranks on Google
```

Something that is weird, is that my wife open a lot tabs on her PC and she never gets that message. We both uses Chrome browser and we are on Static Public IP. Very curious to know Why it is popping up just to me.

By the way now I have switched to Mozilla and I haven't got this issue ...yet. I suspect that one Chrome was doing or trying to do something dodgy.

Do you have any ideas to troubleshoot this (false positive, potential malware, whatever it could be) a bit more?, thanks.

***EDIT: FEW DAYS WITH MOZILLA AND I HAVEN'T GOT THIS ISSUE, almost sure that some add-on on Chrome was causing this "behaviour".***

Comment: "company was under heavy cyberattack  ... wife open a lot tabs on her PC and she never gets that message. "   <-- This really is a question to put to your Company.

Comment: When I'm on my VPN I get that sometimes. I assume it's because other people subscribed to the VPN service are using it to click farm google or something.

Comment: @TravisHeeter Your comment make senses. Now that I switched to Mozilla browser that issue stopped, I believe some add-on on Chrome was doing something wrong.

Comment: @John This happened under my own Public IP, this is why I don't consider raising this to my company, but thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me on Chrome and Edge (on startup page i put www.google) on a windows 10 freshly installed. To Chrome and Edge i have not added any add-on or extension.
I checked the router and only my devices appeared in the list.
As a quick setting to resolve the problem i change the `search engine` and as a result the message never appeared again.

Comment: "*i change the search engine and as a result the message never appeared again*". Do you suggest to not use Google to not receive the message?